# Firebase security rules that check for the incoming request email

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm creating a Flutter Todo app that allow users to add a task for himself or he could send it to another user via their account email.

My Firebase database have the following fields:
title, isChecked, recipient, sender, senderUID
[image]

My current Firebase security rules are as following

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

 function isOwnerOrAdmin(reminder, auth) {
  let isOwner = auth.token.email == reminder.recipient;
  let isAdmin = auth.token.isAdmin == true;
  return isOwner || isAdmin;
 }

 match /todos/{todo} {
  allow create if 
    // User is author
    request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.authorUID;
  allow update, read, delete: if isOwnerOrAdmin(resource.data, request.auth);
  }
 }
}
```

- Is auth.token.email the correct syntax to check for the incoming request email?
- To access to a doccument field (for example: recipient), which one is more syntactically correct, request.resource.data.recipient or resource.data.recipient?

Thank you!

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is auth.token.email the correct syntax to check for the incoming request email?

Yes, since you're passing `request.auth` as your `auth` variable, [`auth.token`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) refers to the token for the user that sent the current request.

> To access to a doccument field (for example: recipient), which one is more syntactically correct, `request.resource.data.recipient` or `resource.data.recipient`?

Both are valid (otherwise you'd have gotten a syntax error when saving these rules), but they do something slightly different.

- `resource.data` is the data as it exists before the current operations start.
- `request.resource.data` is the data as it will exists if the current operation succeeds. So in write operations this contains the modified data.

So you can for example use both to determine whether the data modification that was done is valid/acceptable

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for your answer. I know I rated your answer as accepted but I've been testing and the update/read/delete rule seems not working. It reported in my app that the current request does not have enough permission (which it should be because the user should have the email that's matched with the reminder's recipient email).
Do you know how to debug it or what it might go wrong?

Comment: To debug, you can either use the emulator suite and [use the `debug` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug) there to log all values. If you want our help in debugging, I recommend opening a new question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which should then also include the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Hi Frank, I posted a new question here with all the info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099872/firebase-security-rules-checks-for-the-incoming-request-and-database-collection. Thank you