# Firebase security rules checks for the incoming request and database collection email

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm creating a Flutter Todo app that allow users to add a task for himself or he could send it to another user via their account email.

My Firebase database have the following fields: title, isChecked, recipient, sender, senderUID
[image]

My current Firebase security rules are as following

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

 function isOwnerOrAdmin(reminder, auth) {
  let isOwner = auth.token.email == reminder.recipient;
  let isAdmin = auth.token.isAdmin == true;
  return isOwner || isAdmin;
 }

 match /reminders/{reminder} {
  allow create: if
        // User is author
        request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.senderUID;
  
  allow update: 
        // User is recipient or admin
        if isOwnerOrAdmin(resource.data, request.auth) &&
        // only 'title' and 'isChecked' could be modified
        request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).unchangedKeys().hasAll([
          "recipient",
          "sender",
          "senderUID"
          ]);
          
  // Can be read or deleted by recipent or admin
  allow read, delete: if isOwnerOrAdmin(resource.data, request.auth);
  }
```

In my code, I'm using the following code to make updates to a task,

```
var collection = _firestore.collection('reminders');
var snapshot = await collection.where('title', isEqualTo: task.title).where('recipient', isEqualTo: loggedInUser.email.toString()).get();
await snapshot.docs.first.reference.update({'isChecked': task.isChecked});
```

Similarly, the following code is used to delete a task

```
var collection = _firestore.collection('reminders');
var snapshot = await collection.where('title', isEqualTo: task.title).where('recipient', isEqualTo: loggedInUser.email.toString()).get();
await snapshot.docs.first.reference.delete();
```

Update and Delete do not work with my new set of rules with the INSUFFICIENT PERMISSION in the output, what did I do wrong? I could only create new doccument, but can't update or delete it (via code).

Comment: Can you show in both cases, the data of document to update or delete and the uid + custom claims of the current user?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, the update/delete does not deal with the uid of the user?
For example, in my code I'm trying to change the 'isChecked' field of a doccument that match with the recipient email and the title, but then when it looks up the doccuments, somehow it does not have enought permission, probably from the check OwnerOrAdmin function.

Comment: What is the uid of the user making the update/delete? And what is the doc content?

Comment: @l1b3rty I only use one account to test and I verified within my app that the uid from the request matches with the one on the doccument ("Za80ww20NKdon1oxBLwmscbEADO2"). The title of the document is "Buy Egg" and I'm trying to change the "isCheck" field

Comment: Your `isOwnerOrAdmin()` function is only checking for the auth email and the document's field `recipient`. Have you already checked if the authentication email is the same with the document's `recipient`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the current user is not an admin and the `isAdmin` field is not set. Can you try the following:

```
let isAdmin = auth.get(["token", "isAdmin"], false);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion by changing that line and testing with setting "allow update: 
        if isOwnerOrAdmin(resource.data, request.auth);"

The output I have when I tried to update the isCheck field is "[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(reminders where title==Buy Groceries order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}"